# Using AMMM or Huge Pages for Oracle 11g R2 Database

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, linux, memory

I'm running an Oracle production 11gR2 database which has around 65Gb of data, running with a 4Gb SGA & 40Mb PGA using ASMM.

Now, I have a memory increase up to 32Gb. I'm planning to increase the SGA and PGA for the database but I don't know which one I should use - AMMM or HugePages? I'm using Linux 6 (RHEL?).

Comment: Isn't 11 R2 coming to [end of life](https://mikedietrichde.com/2015/10/17/extended-support-fee-for-oracle-11-2-0-4-waived-until-may-31-2017-extended-support-until-dec-2020/)? Go to [this site](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/articles-11g#db11g_release_2_installations) and see what they have to say - it's the best Oracle install site on the web!

Answer (score 0):

This is what Oracle says about it:

[About HugePages](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E37355/html/ol_about_hugepages.html)

> If you have a system with more than 16GB of memory running Oracle
>   databases with a total System Global Area (SGA) larger than 8GB, you
>   should enable the HugePages feature to improve database performance.